# Connecting selected row event to mvvmlight command

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm writing WPF application, that's using MVVMLight. I have a DataGrid and I wanna connect event of selecting row to command. That's the easy part. The hard(for me of course ;]) part is to get the entity that's connected with the selected row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have many ways of doing so.

The first one would be to pass the selected row as a command parameter. You can do this by XAML or code-behind.

```
<GridView x:Name="gv">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedRowCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=gv}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</GridView>
```

You can also create a selected item property in your view model and bind it to your control.

```
<GridView x:Name="gv" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}">
</GridView>
```

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    public RowType SelectedRow
    {
        get { return _selectedRow; }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            // selection changed, do something here
        }
    }
}
```